# AVR C Programming - Global Arrays

Tags: c, avr

I'm trying to use a global array to store data that I know won't be greater than 255 bytes. But when I try to transmit my data using the array, nothing seems to transmit. What am I doing wrong?

```
char responseFrame[255];

int main {
    ...
    while(1){
        getData();
    }

};
void getData(void) {
    int responseLen = USART1_RX();
    // put data in the response frame
    for (int i = 0; i < responseLen; i++){
        recv_data = USART1_RX();
        responseFrame[i]=recv_data;
        //USART0_TX(responseFrame[i]);
    }

    LogOutput(responseFrame, responseLen);
}

void LogOutput(char *msg, int size) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        USART0_TX(msg[i]);
    }
}
```

However, when I comment the my logging function "LogOutput" and use a straight transmit using the line "USART0_TX(responseFrame[i])", it appropriately transmit the information.

Here is my USART0_TX function:

```
void USART0_TX(uint8_t myData) {
    // Wait if a byte is being transmitted
    while( !(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );
    // Transmit data
    UDR0 = myData;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your LogOutput function is being passed valid data?

This should work

```
unsigned char* data = responseFrame;
LogOutput(data,255);
```

Another thought:

Are you running the compiler with any optimizations? Try turning them off to see if the problem goes away.

Also, you may want to consider marking the global volatile.

```
volatile char data[255];
```

Comment: That outputs, 255 NULL (0x00) characters. Doesnt seem like my LogOutput is being passed valid data, though if I use the "USART0_TX(responseFrame[i]);" directly in the for loop (which is commented out, it transmits properly... hmm. Is this a scope issue?

Comment: `responseFrame` is global so what happens if you replace `msg` with `responseFrame` in LogOutput? It seems a little weird to be passing in a global variable.

Comment: @Justin I'm expecting a 7 byte long array from the sensor, so replacing it as you said transmits 7 NULL (0x00) bytes.

Comment: I'm posting my USART0_TX() function just in case!

Comment: When I stop using the function and drop what's in "getData" directly into my main function, this works fine... I dont get it.

Comment: 2 questions: what happens when you output just the pointer and what happens when you change cast  msg[i] to uint8_t?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply to this thread but it was a newbie error in my code. Please scrap this question as it was an error on my part. @rhooligan Your method is correct, though I rewrote my code to accommodate other things (such as separate files and using `extern` and so on). Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put a delay in your USART0_TX function.

```
// Wait if a byte is being transmitted
while( !(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );
// Transmit data
UDR0 = myData;
_delay_ms(250);
```

This will allow the uC to catch up with the data that gets put on the bus. I've run into a similar issue with transmitting data and I found that using a short delay after putting the data on the UDR solved the problem.

The reason it works in your getData function is because the other two statements act as a delay with respect to your TX function.

You will need to include util/delay.h if you haven't already. Keep in mind that the max delay is 4294967.295 ms/ F_CPU in MHz

Ref: [AVR LibC delay.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html)